# not able to pull data in factory by online json files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html

I created a factory named **service.js**

```
myAppServices=angular.module('myAppServices',['ngResource']);

myAppServices.factory('ProfileData',['$resource', function($resource){
    return $resource('http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.txt', {}, {
        query: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
    });
}]);
```

and my controller is:

```
myAppControllers.controller('ProfileListCtrl',['$scope', 'ProfileData', '$timeout', function($scope, ProfileData, $timeout) {
    var promise = ProfileData.query();
    promise.$promise.then(function(response) {
        $scope.data= response;
        console.log($scope.data);
});    
    }]);
```

I am not getting any console here because of unable to fetch data.
please help me here.

- **Note**

: ***If I am using saved file address instead of online url of json file then its working***.

Comment: I do have "a console" error here and it is about Access-Control-Allow-Origin...

Answer (score 0):

**controller.js**

```
(function () {
    angular
            .module('app')
            .controller('ProfileListCtrl', ProfileListCtrl);

    ProfileListCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'ProfileDataFactory'];

    function ProfileListCtrl($scope, ProfileDataFactory) {
        $scope.data = [];
        function init() {
            ProfileDataFactory.get().then(function (response) {
                angular.copy(response, $scope.data);
                console.log(response);
            });
        }

        init();
    }
}());
```

**factory.js**

```
(function () {
    angular
            .module('app')
            .factory('ProfileDataFactory', ProfileDataFactory);

    ProfileDataFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

    function ProfileDataFactory($http) {

        var self = this;

        self.get = $http.get('http://www.w3schools.com/json/myTutorials.txt').then(function (response) {
            return response.data;
        });

        return self;

    }
}());
```

Comment: I do have "a console" error ALSO here and it is about Access-Control-Allow-Origin...

Comment: @vinjenzo There is a lot options to resolve this problem. The first one: install this plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi Second one: read about CORS http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: I know how to solve this problem, I am commenting pointing out that there is actually an issue that the questioner could see in the console AND that your answer doesn`t give a solution to the real problem @infaustus